# Node.js process is killed for no reason? mongoose overload? etc

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, sorting

I've been struggling with this in the past couple of days.
I have a code that supposed to sort one array of objects into 3 different arrays, and then adding each object of these 3 arrays to 3 different collections in my mongoose-based DB.

I print in the console the objects it added to the collection, and it seems to work for the first 1000 object (give or take), and then it just throws different kinds of errors, the most recent one was:
[image]

I'll try as much as I can to explain why I know for sure that the error message is not cause directly by the code, but by some limitation that i might don't take into consideration:

I have a collection of "websites",
each one has an array of "keywords" - each item in this array is an ID reference to a keyword that was sorted and was added to the "keywords" collection in the DB.
When I sort the keywords, I find the website, and then I add each keyword to from the previous sorting to the array.
Now it works good and adds at least 1,000 keywords to its array, before something goes wrong and it suddenly can't find the app.

What can it be?
the DB setup is like this:

```
var option = {
    server: {
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 300000,
            connectTimeoutMS: 300000
        }
    },
    replset: {
        socketOptions: {
            keepAlive: 300000,
            connectTimeoutMS: 300000
        }
    }
};

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASEURL, option);
```

Is it possible I need to add following configuration to how mongoose operates?
, it does it without a problem. So if I have to guess it has something to do with multiples queries submitted to mongoose at once.

Thanks!

Update, this is some of the outputs (along with the way it generates some errors but doesn't crash...) for some reason it stops way long before it's done going over the whole list (meaning it only added around 500 keywords, when it supposed to add more than 2500... it just stops:
[image]

[image]
[image]

Another edit, with the code where it breaks:
[image]

Comment: Can you update your question to show your code where this error occurs?

Comment: added, thnanks!

Comment: also, please see attached, where it shows that it actually doesn't go over all the keywords, but only on part of it

Comment: someone out there?

Comment: Presumably you're calling `appKeysArray` in a synchronous loop which is queuing up thousands of `findOne` queries (without waiting for them, or the `save` to finish) which may be creating the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Hi Johnny! Thank you very much for your reply. Haven't thought about that, I'll check it out and update. thanks!!